# Obtaining Facebook Likes for Multiple Users using FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm trying to replicate the results of the graph api call:

`graph.facebook.com/[fbid]/likes`

using FQL so that I can obtain the likes of multiple people using a single call. Anyone know if this is possible / how to do it?

Comment: Hmmm, having a quick look on FB documentation..it seems that the method provided can actually give you a list of users who liked an object! which is exactly the opposite...it seems that you can't even get the likes of a single user!

Comment: Actually the method above can be used either with a user fbid to get a list of their likes or with an object id to get a list of the users that like the object

Answer (score 0):

FQL can supposedly support multiqueries. Check out this page:
[FQL Multiquery](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.multiquery/)

which says:

```
"query2":"SELECT name, url, pic FROM profile WHERE id IN (SELECT uid FROM #query1)"
```

Comment: Yes but unfortunately the user_id field of the "likes" fql table is not indexable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SELECT page_id,name FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM page_fan   WHERE uid in (....)`. Hope this was helpful. I found the answer in this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528850/get-all-of-a-users-likes-all-of-them-with-fql). Since this was one of the first pages I came across, I thought I should link it to the answer